# Examples for sequences in the $\ell^{\infty}$ sequence space

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Can I give the sequance $\frac{1}{2^i}~,{i=0\dots \infty}$ and $\frac{1}{3^i}~,{i=0\dots \infty}$ , as examples for sequences in the $\ell^{\infty}$ sequance space ?.  As I can see, all elements are bounded, and the sup-norm is 1.

If not, can you give me why they are not, and give some interesting examples ?

Comment: They are. ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it goes through.

Perhaps the following is an interesting example?

$(x_{i})=(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,...)$, $\|(x_{i})\|_{\infty}=4$.